# In Oracle SQL Developer, how do I create or update a procedure and have the schema name be a variable

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer, how do I create or update a procedure and have the schema name be a variable?
The code below does not work.

```
define my_schema_name = 'schema_1';  


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_schema_name.updateDBUSER(
     p_userid IN DBUSER.USER_ID%TYPE,
     p_username IN DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

  UPDATE DBUSER SET USERNAME = p_username where USER_ID = p_userid;

  COMMIT;

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use the variable properly in your script:

```
DEFINE MY_SCHEMA_NAME = 'SCHEMA1'
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE &my_schema_name..updateDBUSER(
       p_userid IN DBUSER.USER_ID%TYPE,
       p_username IN DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE DBUSER SET USERNAME = p_username where USER_ID = p_userid;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Best of luck.